# Duplicated code in switch cases that needs executing

Tags: ios, swift, enums, switch-statement

I have the following `enum` which handles the UI state.

```
enum UIState {
    case loading
    case populated
    case empty
    case error(Error)
}
```

In view controllers, I use a `switch` to check against each state and update the UI accordingly.

```
private func updateUI() {
    switch state {
    case .loading:
        showProgressView()
    case .populated, .empty:
        hideProgressView()
    case .error(let error):
        hideProgressView()
        showErrorAlert(error)
    }
}
```

The `hideProgressView()` method needs to be called in all cases except `loading`. In the `error` case, I am showing an alert *in addition* to calling the `hideProgressView()` method.

As you can see there is a small duplication of code where I'm calling the `hideProgressView()` method in two cases. Is there a way to consolidate the repeating method calls under one case? I tried the following way,

```
switch state {
case .loading:
    showProgressView()
case .error(let error):
    showErrorAlert(error)
case .populated, .empty, .error:
    hideProgressView()
}
```

But I get the following warnings on the last case.

> Case is already handled by previous patterns; consider removing it
>
> Case will never be executed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the easiest way would be something like this:

```
switch state {
    case .loading:
        showProgressView()
    case .error(let error):
        showErrorAlert(error)
        fallthrough
    case .populated, .empty:
        hideProgressView()
    }
```

You can get more info at: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ControlFlow.html#ID140

Comment: Thank you! I looked into `fallthrough` too but I made the mistake of adding the `error` case again in the last step which caused an error.